# How do I exit from Visual Studio chordal entry mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This should be an easy question but I didn't find the answer after searching.

I accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> in Visual Studio 2010, resulting in the message "Ctrl+R was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...".  I can no longer use normal key commands.
I tried exiting with <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> again, to no avail,
How do I get exit this chordal mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try another valid shortcut, for example `ctr+k+c`, and it should go back to normal.

Comment: What does `Ctrl+k+C` do?

Comment: @A.E.Drew It's shortcut for comment. Shortcut for uncomment is `ctrl+k+u`. I'm suggesting that typing in any shortcut will unlock "shortcut mode", and this is just an example.

Comment: This works, but I would hope that there is a command to escape chordal entry mode without any other side effects.